# limits to infinity when x goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I'm trying to prove this theorem: if $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(f\left(x\right)\:\cdot \:f\left(\frac{13}{5}x\right)\right)\:=\:\infty$ then $\lim _{x\to \infty }f\left(x\right)\:=\:\infty$.

I acctualy tried to disprove it by a counterexample when f(x) is a split function that gives the value 1 for integers and the value of $X^2$ when x is a fraction, but when x goes to infinity it's the same...

Later I thought that it must be true because if the multiplication of a function by itself has limit in infinity infinity, then the function itself should also have limit at infinity, but I don't know how to prove it.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Without continuity? This is false. Take $f$ to be defined as $f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{ if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\-x&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: but how does this function "works" for x goes to infinity? it doesn't matter if x is rational or irrational.

Comment: If $x$ is rational, then so is $\frac{13}{5}x$, and the product is  $\frac{13}{5}x^2$. If $x$ is irrational, then so is $\frac{13}{5}x$, and the product is  $\frac{13}{5}x^2$. So the product does go to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Yet, $f$ has no limit when $x\to\infty$, as it oscillates between arbitrarily large negative and positive values.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Comment: Now, if you meant to restrict the question to continuous functions only, the above example does not apply anymore.

Comment: Have a look at f(x)=-x as a counterexample